# Select Max of sum Value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database  like this :

```
m  | v
-------
1  | 10
1  | 15
1  | 15
2  | 8
2  | 12
2  | 14
3  | 25
3  | 15
3  | 18
4  | 12
```

I want select maximum of sum `v` group by `m` and in first step I create table with this code :

#### First Code:

```
select m,sum(v) as v from table group by m
```

#### First result:

```
m  | v
-------
1  | 35
2  | 34
3  | 54
4  | 12
```

and for select max in this table my code is :

#### Second Code:

```
select max(v) as v,m from 
  (select sum(v) as v,m from table group by `m`)ta
```

#### Second result:

```
v  | m
------
54 | 1
```

#### Correct result:

```
v  | m
------
54 | 3
```

i haven't any idea for solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select m,sum(v) as v from table group by m ORDER BY v DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
 SELECT v,m from 
  (SELECT SUM(v) as v, m FROM maxValues GROUP BY `m`) ta
ORDER BY v DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(select max(sum(v)), m as v,m from table group by `m`)
```